# problem convert idl to tlb

Tags: c#

i try to get a selected text and the word under mouse in firefox

after a lot of search i get the solution that i must  access a document's HTML in Firefox using IAccessible

i found that solution in c++ in this link 
[How to access a document's HTML in Firefox using IAccessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542395/how-to-access-a-documents-html-in-firefox-using-iaccessible)

the solution use ISimpleDOMNode.idl file so the first step to convert that solution from c++ to c# is convert

ISimpleDOMNode.idl to tlb file and convert tlb to dll fill

i try to use VS Command Prompt with this command to convert to tlb file
midl ISimpleDOMNode.idl

but That generate ISimpleDOMNode.h and ISimpleDOMDocument.h, which define the interfaces. It also create ISimpleDOMNode_i.c and ISimpleDOMDocument_i.c   but there is no tlb file

what is the wrong ?

this the link of ISimpleDOMNode.idl file

http://www.4shared.com/file/MddCFmXa/ISimpleDOMNode.html

Comment: You're trying to create a COM object that implements IAccessible? Why do you need the .tlb? Isn't that just for clients of your object that need to use a new interface you've defined?

Comment: ... or if you're actually trying to get an IAccessible *from* Firefox then you certainly don't need a .tlb. You're consuming objects, not creating them.

Comment: i get an  IAccessible object Already but can not access a document's html like this problem in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542395/how-to-access-a-documents-html-in-firefox-using-iaccessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface ISimpleDOMNode : IUnknown {
    // etc..
}
```

That's where the buck stops, IUnknown derived interfaces are not Automation compatible.  They are usable from C++ code, note the .h files generated by midl and the amount of cpp_quote() in the .idl file.  An Automation compatible COM interface is derived from IDispatch and uses the sub-set of Automation compatible types for the function arguments.  Variant, BSTR and SafeArray are popular choices.

Technically it is possible to re-declare the interface types in C# code, you just don't get any help from a type library to get that right.  And you'll have to deal with the no-multiple-inheritance headache (not this one).  Tlbimp.exe is powerless without a type library.

Use C++/CLI to get this going, you can write a ref class wrapper and you can #include the .h file.

Comment: many thanks Hans Passant , but i do not know how to use c++ ,can you help me