# document.body.addEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm working on a screen reader project and I needed to get the paragraph under the cursor. To do that in Firefox, I wrote an extension, to which my screen reader connects through sockets and gets the text. I needed to get the current element under the cursor and the function worked fine in a sample html page written by myself (So there is no problem with the function).

But when I try to attach the function to my JS file in the extension, It seems that the function which is called by "document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',myfunc(mEvent),false);" is never called.
But if I call

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function(mEvent){...},true);
```

myfunc is called.

I'm new to javascript, so excuse me if it's a stupid question, But why the

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function(mEvent){...},true);
```

is not working?

I always appreciated your nice helps and ideas. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, I hope that it is helpful nevertheless. Using an extension for a screen reader is unnecessary, in particular you might not want to update that extension regularly as the browser's user interface changes. Firefox supports [a number of accessibility APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessibility/AT-APIs#Supported_AT_APIs) which you can use directly from your application. These APIs have the advantage of being stable, once your implementation is done it should continue working (as far as I remember there was only one occasion where Mozilla broke compatibility with existing screen readers).

As to the actual question: you didn't tell anything about the context in which this code is executing. Normally, extensions run code in their XUL overlay meaning that the context is the browser window, not the web page. Which would explain why your code isn't working (it's a XUL document, no `document.body` there). What you probably mean is attaching an event listener to the `<tabbrowser>` element where the web pages are loaded: `gBrowser.addEventListener(...)`. Side-note: If you really wanted to catch all events on a XUL document you should register an event listener on `document` or `document.documentElement`.

Btw, you can see error messages related to extensions in the [Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console) (the article I link to explains how to enable it in the current Firefox versions).

Comment: Many good things to learn from your scientific answer. But for the screen reader, I had to use  ISimpleDOMNode.idl and my code is in c#, and it has some problems as mentioned in the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642081/problem-convert-idl-to-tlb). After many searching, I found that a solution is to use extensions and sockets. But now I think it's the time to add wrappers and using ISimpleDOMNode.idl!  Many special thanks for your nice and valuable reply. I try to keep them in my mind.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Add height to a body element.

```
<html>
<style>
    .vh {
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<body class="vh">
    <script>
        document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('mouse click');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be other issues here, but the syntax of your `addEventListener` call is incorrect and could be causing the issue you are seeing:

`document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',myfunc(mEvent),false);` is actually invoking "myfunc" at the same time you are invoking `addEventListener` and passing it as the second parameter.

You should instead be calling it this way:

`document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function() { myfunc(mEvent) },false);`

Comment: Thanks Matt, but to be accurate, I called addEventListener like this in my project: document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',
 function(mEvent){...},false);  Is it wrong? (Sorry for being inaccurate and unclear in the question)

Comment: OK, that's correct then - I recommend correcting it in your question just to clarify.

Comment: @Luke: I suggest you try again - with your correction the question is very confusing now. I think you changed the wrong code line.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the document is not yet ready, so there is nothing to bind to. Try adding an `onload="addMyEventListener();"` to your `<body>` and see if that fixes things up. I don't know the proper way to time things, so maybe someone else can chime in with the best way to handle this.

Comment: I guess you're right (to my limited knowledge of JavaScript, It seems correct). But I'm writing an extension, so I don't have the <body>. But I think as you said the document is not yet ready when I call the function.

Comment: I am on the train so cannot look it up for you. Do a search on mimicking jquery's document.ready. That is what you want to do 8I think.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and now solved it. After closing  tag, try adding an `document.body.addEventListener`. Parser didn't recognize DOM object of the "addEventListener" event because HTML tag of DOM object is not closed.

Refer to following. It works well.

```
<html>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.addEventListener('click', function() { ... });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice to put contents out of the `<body>` like this?

Comment: Yes, don't put `<script>` tags outside the `<body>` or `<head>`, it won't validate:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037769/1824444

Answer (score 0):

following Wladimir Palant's advise, the follow is working:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() { ... }, false);
```