# Javascript Code is not excuting on Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a JS code that is not currently not executing on Chrome Console. I have tried indenting the code differently.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var myParent = document.getElementById("Banner"); 
  var myImage = document.createElement("img");
  myImage.src = 'https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif';
  myParent.appendChild(myImage);
  myImage.style.marginLeft = "160px";
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what it *is* doing.  "It isn't working" is not descriptive enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.body.addEventListener is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167969/document-body-addeventlistener-is-not-working)

Comment: It is working for me (minus the fact that appendChild is not working since there is I assume no Banner element) but the event is hooked to the body and triggers. What is your problem with it?

Comment: The code when put into console should execute a gif of a cat playing once you click anywhere on the webpage. However the response I get instead is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:5:12)
(anonymous) @ VM49:5" does appendChild not work